# Does "Personal Use" mean I can earn from it?

Tags: licensing

I'm almost done with my personal game. One of the reasons I started this is because of monetization. I plan to monetize it using Google Admob. However, I need some icons - essential part of my game.

And these icons are free, released by a certain company, and they say in their download page:

> These icons are free for personal use or commercial testing purposes.
>   Otherwise, you'll need a Premium or Enterprise license. :)

Question is, does "Personal Use" mean I can earn from it?

Also, this "personal game" is actually "under" a group named, say "XXX".
The group "XXX" is merely a group name, not a company, not legal/registered, just literally a group name on Github. And this group is composed of 3 people and that includes me. Does this kind of setup go under the "personal use"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are earning money from the game, that is commerce, ie. commercial use.

You would need to ask for a licence for commercial use, or replace these assets with ones that permit commercial use.

Comment: Straightforward* answer. Thanks!